# How to make this code run in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, facebook, dynamic, .net-3.5, facebook-c#-sdk

How to convert this to work in .NET 3.5? it does not compile for some reason...
complains about "myInfo.data" missing Microsoft CSharp reference that is used in .NET 4.0.

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Perms = "user_about_me,friends_about_me" };

if (auth.Authorize())
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient(auth.Session.AccessToken);
    dynamic myInfo = fb.Get("/me/friends");
    foreach (dynamic friend in myInfo.data  )
    {
        Response.Write("Name: " + friend.name + "<br/>Facebook id: " + friend.id + "<br/><br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568452/dynamic-keyword-problem

Comment: Possible duplicates:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675364/accessing-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-result-object-using-net-3-5-api, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568452/dynamic-keyword-problem

Answer (score 1):

It would be roughly:

```
var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Perms = "user_about_me,friends_about_me" };

if (auth.Authorize())
{
    var fb = new FacebookClient(auth.Session.AccessToken);
    MyInfoType myInfo = (MyInfoType)fb.Get("/me/friends");
    foreach (var friend in myInfo.data)
    {
        Response.Write("Name: " + friend.name + "<br/>Facebook id: " + friend.id + "<br/><br/>");
    }
}
```

What type fb.Get returns?

Comment: It return object. which can either be IDictionary<string, object>, IList<object>, bool, long, double or string. more info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367496/dynamic-object-handle-problem-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/7369388#7369388